# How to create an independent git repository in a folder within a different git repository?

Tags: git, github

I have a git repository in folder **AAA** and then another git repository in folder **BBB**.

What I need to do is to create a new folder in **AAA** where I would copy **BBB** repository, so it would become a subfolder of **AAA**.

The result should be that **AAA** repository stays as it is and excludes **BBB** folder, while when I enter the **BBB** folder it's a new repository of its own that has nothing to do with **AAA**.

Could you please explain me how to do that?

As I understand, I probably could create subfolder **BBB** in **AAA** then add it to .gitignore and then initialize a new repo there? Right? How would I do that? Thank you!

Comment: you should look at git submodules. They are moderately complicated though, so a post on stack overflow might not be the best place for it. here is a link I like that explains it well: https://chrisjean.com/2009/04/20/git-submodules-adding-using-removing-and-updating/.

Comment: Looks like a repeat of this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4659549/maintain-git-repo-inside-another-git-repo).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Maintain git repo inside another git repo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4659549/maintain-git-repo-inside-another-git-repo)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the absolute minimum that you would need to do

```
git init AAA
cd AAA
echo BBB > .gitignore
git init BBB
```

For most scenarios [submodules](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules) is a better solution. But if you want the repositories to be completely independent of each other, this is a way to do it.

Comment: Thanks! you think it's better than using Submodules?

Comment: It's different, if you want the git repos to know about each other then you need to use a submodule. If you want them to purposely not know about each other this is a perfect, simple answer for that.

Comment: @deemeetree no, I think submodules are a far better solution. With them the AAA repository will point to a version in BBB, which is probably what you want.

Comment: @KlasMellbourn in fact no, I don't want AAA to be aware of BBB. Is gitignore better then for that case?