# Vue: Having frontend in it's own Github repo?

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I am working on a Laravel project and part of the app was converted to a Vue app.  Ultimately, the blade file is reading from the source of `/dist/app.js` , which is generated after running `npm run production` and runs the whole Vue app. The company only wants 1 engineer to run deploys to ensure backend code doesn't get inadvertantly changed.

To make strictly frontend changes, can I technically have the src read off a CDN in the Blade file and then just remove the Vue app entirely from the github repo into it's own so I can continuously make changes on my own.  That way, I can make changes and then upload the new bundle to the CDN without touching the backend repo.  Is that doable?

Comment: What you need to is changing `.js` file in your blade to the CDN link, isn't it? So for example, if you're using `{{ mix('js/app.js')` _(which is public/js/app.js)_, you should put CDN url there

Comment: @senty currently in the layout blade, I have `<script type="text/javascript" src="/dist/js/app.js"></script>` ....in my webpack.mix.js folder, I have `mix .js('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'dist/js')` so it's creating the dist folder and generating the app.js file in there

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4659549/maintain-git-repo-inside-another-git-repo) can guide you on what you want to achieve - either symlinks or Git submodules seem to achieve what you need