# Tracking a pushing to a new repository in git

Tags: git, gitlab, bitbucket

I have 2 repositories in git....REPO1 and REPO 2. I have cloned REPO1 and all works fine. I have added 1 additional folder inside the project(REPO1) which I need to checkout/track in one branch inside REPO2. How do I do that.

I have tried git remote -v and git remote set-url origin https://github.com/user/repo2.git as per:
[How to change the URI (URL) for a remote Git repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2432764/how-to-change-the-uri-url-for-a-remote-git-repository)

but when I do a git branch from inside the folder, it still shows the branches in REPO1 and not REPO2.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Maintain git repo inside another git repo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4659549/maintain-git-repo-inside-another-git-repo)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to do is a `submodule`.

Remove the folder (git will create it) and try:

```
git submodule add https://url.of/REPO2
```

See [the documentation](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules) for more information.

Comment: Thanks Orace.. that works. But can I do it the other way round. I mean create a folder in the project and have its tracking set to REPO2. While the remaining part or the project still track to REPO1.