# nested but communicating git repositories

Tags: git, git-submodules, git-subtree

let `upper`, `left`, and `right` be directories as in the following diagram.

```
upper
├── left
└── right
```

#### question

how do i best manage these with git as local git repositories such that

- each `upper`, `left` and `right` has a separate git repository,
- histories from the repositories of `left` and `right` can be somehow propagated to the repository of `upper`,
- histories from the repository `upper` can be somehow propagated to the repositories of `left` and `right`,

both of the latter preferably being done without changing the corresponding work-trees `upper`, `left`, and `right`?

#### example

for clarity, call the git repositories of `upper`, `left` and `right` just `upper.git` `left.git` and `right.git` respectively. (you can imagine them as bare repositories entirely outside the mentioned directory structure.) first

- i work on `left` and commit to `left.git`; then
- i somehow propagate the history from `left.git` to `upper.git`, so the latter knows about all the work i have done; then
- i work on `upper`, sometimes working on files in `right`, and commit to `upper.git`; then
- i somehow propagate the history from `upper.git` to `right.git`, so the latter knows about all the work i have done on files in `right`.

#### thoughts

initially i thought that i could realise this by using git subtree. but when i try to include the repository for `left` in `upper` using `git subtree -P left add ⟨left.git⟩ master`, i - perhaps unsurprisingly - get:

```
fatal: prefix 'left' already exists.
```

i have searched similar questions on stackoverflow, regarding nested repositories, but i quite don’t see how they relate to my problem. i probably don’t understand git subtrees well enough and perhaps i’m a bit too simple-minded in general. i have not looked deeply into git submodules; it seems to me that they are meant for something else.

Answer (score 3):

It's not quite clear what is your ultimate goal for such a structure.
If you only plan on keeping all these repos local - there is no need for submodules.

If you want upper repo (not folder) to contain all changes from inner repos (separate commit tree) you could try some answers from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4659549/maintain-git-repo-inside-another-git-repo).

On the other hand I don't see any reason to do so. If all you want is just keep changes of folders in different repositories - create independent repos, and treat them as such. In this case `upper.git` repo (not folder) will ignore all changes of inner repos. Each inner repo will keep track of it own folder.